# Index variable range in numpy

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have a numpy zero matrix `A` of the shape `(2, 5)`.

```
A = [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

I have another array `seq` of size `2`. This is same as the first axis of `A`.

```
seq = [2, 3]
```

I want to create another matrix `B` which looks like this:

```
B = [[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]
```

`B` is constructed by changing the first `seq[i]` elements in the `ith` row of `A` with `1`.

This is a toy example. `A` and `seq` can be large so efficiency is required. **I would be extra thankful if someone knows how to do this in tensorflow.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in TensorFlow (and with some analogous code in NumPy) as follows:

```
seq = [2, 3]

b = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(5), 0)   # A 1 x 5 matrix.
seq_matrix = tf.expand_dims(seq, 1)  # A 2 x 1 matrix.
b_bool = tf.greater(seq_matrix, b)   # A 2 x 5 bool matrix.

B = tf.to_int32(b_bool)              # A 2 x 5 int matrix.
```

Example output:

```
In [7]: b = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(5), 0)
        [[0 1 2 3 4]]

In [21]: b_bool = tf.greater(seq_matrix, b)
In [22]: op = sess.run(b_bool)
In [23]: print(op)
[[ True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False]]

In [24]: bint = tf.to_int32(b_bool)
In [25]: op = sess.run(bint)
In [26]: print(op)
[[1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This `@mrry's` solution, expressed a little differently

```
In [667]: [[2],[3]]>np.arange(5)
Out[667]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
In [668]: ([[2],[3]]>np.arange(5)).astype(int)
Out[668]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

The idea is to compare [2,3] with [0,1,2,3,4] in an 'outer' broadcasting sense.  The result is boolean which can be easily changed to 0/1 integers.

Another approach would be to use [`cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) (or another [`ufunc.accumulate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) function):

```
In [669]: A=np.zeros((2,5))
In [670]: A[range(2),[2,3]]=1
In [671]: A
Out[671]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
In [672]: A.cumsum(axis=1)
Out[672]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
In [673]: 1-A.cumsum(axis=1)
Out[673]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Or a variation starting with `1's`:

```
In [681]: A=np.ones((2,5))
In [682]: A[range(2),[2,3]]=0
In [683]: A
Out[683]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.]])
In [684]: np.minimum.accumulate(A,axis=1)
Out[684]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: This is a great solution using numpy.